# For loop for image editing: use output image from the loop as input for the next iteration

Tags: r, image, for-loop, image-editing

I'm trying to create a series of black and white images of visual noise, in which each image is identical to the previous one except for a proportion of random pixels which have swapped colours (black pixels turn white, and white pixels turn black).

I can generate the images individually, but now I want to put the code in a loop so I can generate and save a sequence of 300 images. However, I am having some trouble. There are multiple problems with my loop as I've tried to cobble it together from a combination of other questions and answers on stack overflow, and I don't fully understand what I'm doing (I'm new to programming).

Here's my code:

```
file_names <- c("VN1", "VN2", "VN3", "VN4", "VN5")
next_image <- c()

for (i in 1:5) {
    im <- if (i == 1) {        
    load.image("C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/VN_images/VN.png")
    } else {
    load.image(next_image)
    }
        df <- as.data.frame(im) %>%
        mutate(colour = case_when(value == 0 ~ "black", TRUE ~ "white")) %>%
        group_by(colour) %>%
        mutate(value = replace(value, sample(row_number(), size = ceiling(0.05 * n()), replace = FALSE), 3))
    df$value[df$value == 3 & df$colour == "black"] <- 1
    df$value[df$value == 3 & df$colour == "white"] <- 0
    df1 <- df[, -4]
    new_image <- as.cimg(df1, dims = c(150,100))
    save.image(new_image, "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/VN_images/", file_names[i], ".png")
    next_image <- c(next_image, new_image)    
}
```

EDIT: question edited to fix error highlighted by @nrennie below

My main problem at the moment appears to be saving the new image that is generated by the code - I need each new file to have a different name and for the names to preserve the sequence in which they were generated - and then loading the new image in the next iteration of the loop.

With the code as above I get the error message "Error in save.image(new_image, "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/VN_images/",  :
unused argument (".png")"

If I change the file path to "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/VN_images/A.png" the code will run once and save an image named "A.png", but also return the error "Error in if (is.url) { : the condition has length > 1" so there also appears to be a problem loading the new image in the second iteration.

I've looked at several previous answers to similar questions (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819102/run-next-iteration-on-output-from-previous-iteration-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661799/use-result-of-previous-loop-as-input-for-next-loop), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593768/n1-loop-in-r-how-to-use-first-loop-output-in-the-next-iteration-of-the-loop),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805911/can-i-create-a-for-loop-in-r-to-save-images), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324232/how-to-save-files-with-different-names-using-for-loops-in-r?rq=3), but I'm struggling to apply the answers to my own problem.

Comment: Did you try running it line by line - does it fail on the first iteration (e.g. when i = 1), or on one of the others? Can you also clarify which packages you are using?

Comment: @nrennie I don't actually know how to run it line by line - I'm using RStudio if that makes a difference? For the entire sequence, including generating the first image I'm using imager, dplyr, tidyr and magick. I think this bit of code only uses imager and dplyr, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: In your else statement, `next_image` has initially been defined as an empty vector, and then you run `load.image(next_image)`. You appear to be loading an empty vector - the error may be coming from `load.image` here?  Should your for loop also be `i in 1:5`, not `i in 5`?

Comment: @nrennie changing `i in 5` to `i in 1:5` produces a different error: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `colour = case_when(value == 0 ~ "black", TRUE ~
  "white")`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error:
! object 'value' not found

Yes you're right about the empty vector - what I want to do is create `next_image` within the loop and use that as the input for each iteration after the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work through trial and error and a bit of help offline. Posting the code below in case it helps anyone else in future

```
library(imager)
library(dplyr)

file_names <- c("VN1", "VN2", "VN3", "VN4", "VN5")
next_image <- NULL

for (i in 1:5) {
  if (i == 1) {
    im <- load.image("C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/VN_images/VN.png")
  } else {
    im <- next_image
  }

  df <- as.data.frame(im) %>%
    mutate(colour = case_when(value == 0 ~ "black", TRUE ~ "white")) %>%
    group_by(colour) %>%
    mutate(value = replace(value, sample(row_number(), size = ceiling(0.05 * n()), replace = FALSE), 3))

  df$value[df$value == 3 & df$colour == "black"] <- 1
  df$value[df$value == 3 & df$colour == "white"] <- 0
  df1 <- df[, -4]
  new_image <- as.cimg(df1, dims = c(150, 100))
  save.image(new_image, paste0("C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/VN_images/", file_names[i], ".png"))

  next_image <- new_image    
}
```